# Azerothcore lua script doesnt work or load

Tags: module, lua, azerothcore

i tried to write a script that removes poor (grey) items from the creature loot table globally, without touching the database. But it does not work and i can't figure out why because i am very new to lua programming and azerothcore in general.

i am using this azerothcore version:
AzerothCore rev. 96a5224d927f+ 2023-04-22 07:25:31 +0700 (npcbots_3.3.5 branch) (Win64, Release, Static)

This is my script, it is stored in the lua_scripts folder with other lua scripts that seem to work:

```
-- Function to check if an item is grey (common)
function IsGreyItem(item)
    local itemQuality = item:GetQuality()
    return itemQuality == 0 -- 0 represents poor quality (common)
end

-- Hook into the loot drop event globally
function OnLoot(event, player, creature)
    local loot = creature:GetLoot()

    if not loot then
        return
    end

    for i = loot:GetSize(), 1, -1 do
        local item = loot:GetItem(i)

        if item and IsGreyItem(item) then
            -- Grey item found, remove it from the loot
            loot:RemoveItem(i)
        end
    end
end

-- Register the loot event handler globally
RegisterPlayerEvent(27) -- Register the loot event (ID 27) globally
AddEvent("OnCreatureLoot", OnLoot)
```

maybe someone has an idea why it doesn't work :)

i killed some low level mobs to check if they still drop grey items and they do.

Answer (score 2):

The event is not registered properly. The syntax is

```lua
cancel = RegisterPlayerEvent( event, function )
```

So you need to replace your last 2 lines by

```lua
RegisterPlayerEvent( 27, OnLoot )
```

However, I suggest writing an SQL query that removes the grey items from the `creature_loot_template` and possibly other tables instead.

A good way to debug scripts, is to add `print` statements. These show text in the worldserver console. Firstly you see if the line is reached at all and you can also easily display values.

Answer (score 0):

You can also deselect the loot option for greys in the bot menu and the bots won't loot them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).